# Similar Neovim mappings--one works, one does not work

Tags: neovim

### Context

Creating remappings to exit TERMINAL mode and enter NORMAL mode within neovim (ie. `<C-\><C-N>`).
I'm getting no-op behavior (ie. terminal stays in TERMINAL mode and simply ouputs `,` -- mapleader) when creating a new mapping as follows (in `init.lua`):

```
keymap.set("t", "<leader><Esc>", "<C-\\><C-N>")
```

Shell is `zsh` and I've set `bindkey -v` in `.zshrc`. Terminal application is `iterm2`.

When I set the following mapping:

```
keymap.set("t", "<leader>nn", "<C-\\><C-N>")
```

The expected behavior happens (ie. terminal exits TERMINAL mode and enter NORMAL mode).
Not sure how/where the first mapping is getting interrupted to not exit TERMINAL mode.

### Question

Why is the first mentioned mapping not working, which the second mentioned mapping is working?

### Effort

Looked on other posts and they all indicate there should be no problem with the first mapping.

Comment: just tried and both mappings worked for me with nvim 0.8.3 (i have `let mapleader = ','`) + iterm2.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. Must be some other plugin messing it up...